# Why is Redshift datediff giving different weeks when it is the same number of day difference?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to find the number of weeks between two days. When the difference is 8 days, I should be getting 1 or 2 weeks, depending on how the function works in Redshift (rounds up or down). However, it should be **consistent** whichever way it chooses.

I realize that I could simply take the number of days and then divide by 7 and do either a ROUND or a CEIL, but I am simply trying to understand why DATEDIFF(weeks, date1, date2) provides either 1 or 2 when I have the two dates different by 8 days.

```
SELECT
DATEDIFF(weeks, '2019-03-17', '2019-03-25') AS week_difference1,
DATEDIFF(days, '2019-03-17', '2019-03-25') AS day_difference1,

DATEDIFF(weeks, '2019-03-16', '2019-03-24') AS week_difference2,
DATEDIFF(days, '2019-03-16', '2019-03-24') AS day_difference2
```

Result:
week_difference1 = 1

day_difference1  = 8

week_difference2 = 2

day_difference2  = 8

Comment: Which db vendor? Version?

Comment: Specifically, DATEDIFF determines the number of datepart boundaries that are crossed between two expressions. For example, if you are calculating the difference in years between two dates, 12-31-2008 and 01-01-2009, the function returns 1 year despite the fact that these dates are only one day apart. If you are finding the difference in hours between two time stamps, 01-01-2009 8:30:00 and 01-01-2009 10:00:00, the result is 2 hours.    https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATEDIFF_function.html

Comment: Thanks donPablo. I am using Amazon Redshift SQL.

So to follow up, there is the 'boundary' for these weeks?

Comment: So I guess a normalized query might be to divide the number of Days by seven --- ( DATEDIFF(days, '2019-03-16', '2019-03-24') / 7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with many software products from the US, the first day of the week in Redshift (at least far as DATEDIFF is concerned) is *Sunday*, and not the ISO standard of Monday. Therefore when calculating the number of weeks between two dates the boundary is Saturday/Sunday.

In your example, the eight days between the 16th March 2019 and 24th March 2019 crosses two week boundaries (one on 16/17 March and one on 23/24 March), so the resulting DATEDIFF value is 2 (two week boundaries crossed).

However, the eight days between the 17th March and 25th March only crosses one week boundary (23/24 March) so the resulting DATEDIFF value is 1.